# DistributionNotFound when running pserve with docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, pyramid, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my simple Pyramid application with docker-compose, below are my docker files:

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:2.7-onbuild
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements_dev.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
db:
  image: mysql:5.6

web:
  build: .
  command: pserve development.ini --reload
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "6543:6543"
  links:
    - db:db
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I get `pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'tenders' distribution was not found and is required by the application`, which is weird, because my application should have been installed using by `pip install -e .` command.

Things are getting weirder:

```
docker-compose run web bash
root@2323b6b2f3ca:/tenders# pip freeze | grep tenders  # no results
root@2323b6b2f3ca:/tenders# pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///tenders
# Skippping most of the outup for more readability
Installing collected packages: tenders
  Running setup.py develop for tenders
Successfully installed tenders
root@2323b6b2f3ca:/tenders# pip freeze | grep tenders
-e git+git@bitbucket.org:xxx/tenders.git@342a8f9101a3e06fa04d71f4eef81b461476d3a5#egg=tenders-master
```

Now when I launch `pserve development.ini --reload` it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong, how can I install my package `tenders` automatically using `pip install -e .` (or any other command)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**:

In the `volumes` section of the service, you can tell Docker to use the `.egg-info` folder from the container instead of from your host mounted volume.

For example, see `/usr/src/app/yourapp.egg-info` in that config:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: pserve development.ini --reload
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app:cached
    - /usr/src/app/yourapp.egg-info
  ports:
    - "6543:6543"
  links:
    - db:db
```

**Previous answer:**

I had the same problem. It happens when the docker volume is mounted.

In your Dockerfile, you install the application with `pip install -e .`, which creates the .egg-info directory in the current directory (in the image). But later, when you use the docker volumes to replace the container source directory with yours, you don't have this .egg-info directory in your host filesystem.

The way I fixed it is that I created a virtualenv in my host filesystem, I ran `python setup.py develop`, but I guess you could run `pip install -e .`. It created the .egg-info directory so that it exists when you run `pserve` from the container. The virtualenv could probably be deleted at that point.

I'm really not sure it's the best solution, but at least, now you know the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you suggest to modify the Dockerfile, create and activate virtualenv and then install the packages?

Comment: No, I created a virtualenv in the host filesystem so that the .egg-info folder exists in the host filesystem. Then, when you start the docker container and mount the volume, the image directory is removed, but the new directory that comes from the host also as the .egg-info directory. It's really not perfect and there's probably a more elegant solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this: `But later, when you use the docker volumes to replace the container source directory with yours, you don't have this .egg-info directory in your host filesystem.`. Why I don't have that directory and my app directory exists (note - I no longer remove the .egg directory in the Dockerfile - see my edit)?

Comment: In your docker-compose config file (`docker-compose.yml`), you probably have a section that starts with `volumes:`. What it does is that it replaces the directory in the container with the one in your host filesystem. In the image, the directory contains the .egg-info directory, because of the `pip install` in the Dockerfile. But when the volumes are mounted in the container, the directory of the image is replaced by the one on your host filesystem, that does not contain the .egg-info file.

Comment: If I created the venv and "pip install -e ." on my host as you did, would it matter if my host is Windows 10 and my docker machine is Ubuntu? Meaning, does the operating system have any bearing on the .egg that's created?